# Is it possible to have different header style blog titles in different categories?

Tags: posts, categories, title

For my category titled 'mindset' I would like to use the following style on my post header:

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 grey;
border-bottom: 5px solid #83990A;
```

However for my 'news' category I would like to use the following style:

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 grey;
```

Any ideas of the coding I could use?

Thanks.

Comment: what theme are you using? does the theme use `post_class()`?

Comment: Michael I'm using a theme called Sevent - tried to get support through them, but sadly to no avail.  Not sure if it uses that...

Comment: unfortunately your theme does not seem to use `post_class()` - so following the suggestion by @Max Yudin is possibly a way to go.

Comment: Any idea on what CSS I need to add?  I'm getting myself very confused!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that any post belongs to only one category.

Create respective CSS classes, e.g. 'news-header' and 'mindset-header', and use following code inside the loop:

```
<?php
// get post categories
$categories = get_the_category();
// get single category
$category = $categories[0];
// echo header with category class
echo '<h2 class="' . $category . '-header">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
```

Comment: That's great thanks. How do I create the CSS for it?  Sorry, I'm trying to learn as I go along here!

Comment: For example my current CSS that covers all post titles is:      .blog-entry h4 a            {font-size:18px !important; color:#ffffff !important; margin-left: 5px !important;}
.blog-entry h4 { 
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 grey;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #83990A;
    font-size: 18px !important;
line-height: 35px !important;
 margin-bottom: 0 !important;}
  }